# RegionPlot3D contour problem

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a little problem and didn't succeed trying to solve it on my own.
Situation is, I need a visualization of the function $s - 3\cdot s\cdot q + q$ as a region on p == 0 if function's value is less than zero, a region on p == 1 if the function > 0, and a contour if the function equals to zero.

What I've done:

```
RegionPlot3D[(s - 3q*s + q > 0 && p == 0) || (s - 3q*s + q <= 0  && p == 1), 
                      {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

which give me this:

[image]

but what I need to add is a contour $s - 3\cdot s\cdot q + q = 0$ to this plot, but also remain able to intersect this set with others.

The contour is simple:

```
ContourPlot3D[s - 3 q*s + q == 0, {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I've tried to use a little hint with inequality range

```
RegionPlot3D[(s - 3 q s + q > 0 && p == 0) || (s - 3 q s + q <= 0 && 
p == 1) || Abs[s - 3 q s + q] < 0.01, {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {p, 
0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoint -> 100]
```

This is sufficiently accurate, but produces a 3d set, instead of a surface.

Any ideas how to reach my goal?

P.S. the best would be a solution to such kind of problems in general, because, sometimes the contour equation can be not that simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using `Show` needs to rearrange the order of ranges in `ContourPlot3D`, e.g. :

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[(s - 3 q*s + q > 0 && p == 0) ||
                     (s - 3 q*s + q <= 0 && p == 1), 
                  {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
     ContourPlot3D[s - 3 q*s + q == 0, {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Here is another solution without `Show`, using only `Plot3D` and `HeavisideTheta` function :

```
Plot3D[ HeavisideTheta[-s + 3 q*s - q], {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, 
        Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
        ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, 1]], 
        MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2/3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Artes! Thanks a lot for this answer, it's very helpful. Although, would I be able to intersect the contour part with other bool sets? I mean, what if I add another condition, using other equation, would it intersect the contour part with it ass well?

Comment: @SergeyAganezovjr You can always use `Plot3D[{f1[x,y],f2[x,y],...,fn[x,y]},{x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax},options]` to plot n functions. Instead of `HeavisideTheta` you can use e.g. `UnitStep`. The latter may depend on more variables.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question.  What is a "3D set" and a "3D surface"?

If you need to combine two 3D graphics, use `Show[graphic1, graphic2]`.  Your surface can be plotted using `Plot3D` as well, but the quality of the discontinuous part will not be excellent:

```
Plot3D[Boole[s - 3 q*s + q < 0], {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Show` to combine two pieces:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[s - 3 q*s + q == 0, {q, 0.1, 1}, {s, 0.1, 1}, {p, 0, 1}],
 Plot3D[Boole[s - 3 q*s + q < 0], {q, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Congrats with your 10k. I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: Well, the difference is that 3D set has a range of s values with constant q, while surface doesn't.